Как лучше всего хранить временные переменные
data = {

 upload(ms = {}) {
    this.upload.sdf = 233;
 }

}

Предположим, обратились к функции upload. Передали массив, вопрос не в этом...
Мне интересно, как лучше всего хранить временные переменные?
Сейчас делаю так, создание переменных
ms.d = ''
ms.x = ''

И тд.
Хотел попробовать this, выдает весь объект, думал
this.upload.sdf = 233;

Что так возможно создать переменные, которые будут крутиться только в функции 'upload'...
Какие есть еще варианты?
Необходимо создать множество переменных, которые будут каждый раз при обращении к функции, удалены, под новые.
Как быть с памятью, если хранить переменные в ms.d = '' и каждый раз обращаться к вункци и задавать новые. От этого память не станет забиваться?

Раз сто прочитал, не понял ничего. Что за временные переменные.... что значит "будут удалены под новые"...зачем что-то удалять и каким образом это будет происходить. Текста много, но ничего не понятно

От этого память не станет забиваться? --- если создавать миллиард переменных - то, может, и забьётся. а от 2-3 или 20-30 - ничего не случится

Необходимо миллиард раз вызвать upload, каждый раз в ней создается миллиард переменных с уникальными значениями.  Работаем с ними, как функция завершит выполнение. Миллиард переменных которые были созданы, больше неактуальны. Осталось вызвать чуть меньше миллиарда...

зачем в методе миллиард переменных? что это за непонятные миллиард переменных? обычно GC убивает всё, что было создано локально после окончания действия этого локального (в данном случае метода). Но вопрос слишком про какого-то сферического коня в вакууме.... правильнее было бы задать вопрос на конкретных данных и примерах

Понял, допустим 3 раза подряд вызываю upload({e:1}) каждый раз создаем допустим 10 переменных которые за креплены за массивом 'ms'. К примеру ms.i = 'одна переменная' . Перед каждым последующим вызовом upload. Те переменные которые были добавлены в ms, понятно что массив другой и их уже не достать. Они также ни в какой памяти не храниться, с каждым последующим разом память не забивается?

@Роман , если вы добавите более полный код, мы можем предложить вам более корректное решение вашей проблемы.

В данном случае upload - не совсем функция. А именнованный элемент объекта с лямбда - функцией. (Стандарт ES5 добавил классы, рекомендую бросать использовать объекты с функциями с этой целью)
JS позволяет издеваться с типами как хотите. Чтобы не плодить временные переменные, вы можете представлять их в интерфейсе в виде лямбд (геттеров), вычисляя их на лету.
Избегайте this, ограничивая область видимости переменных до необходимого уровня, тогда их своевременно очистит cборщик мусора.

PS: Не ES5, а ES2015 (ES6), но я почему-то уверен что ES5 )


переменные

Переменные создаются через let, var и const. Всё остальное - это не переменные.

Передали массив

Не передали. Кода передачи массива в вопросе нет, да и вообще ни одного массива в вопросе нет.

которые будут крутиться только в функции

Это вообще что-то не то.

Необходимо создать множество переменных, которые будут каждый раз при обращении к функции, удалены, под новые.

Ну так и используй переменные, а не какую-то муть.
